# Use Webscarab to modify local html files in javaFX 2.2 through socket

Tags: sockets, proxy, javafx-2

I am able to load an html file in my webengine and sent the traffic through Webscarab with the following code :

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8008");
eng = view.getEngine();          
eng.load("http://##########/");
```

The problem is that I want to load a local html page via the `eng.loadContent(String htmlCode);` method and again send the traffic through Webscarab. When I load the content into the webengine, the Webscarab is running but it does not seem to interfere the communication.

My goal is to achieve a communication through socket between a client and a server. The server which is a java program, run in the same machine as the Apache server, where i have my html and php pages. When the user makes a correct log in to the server, the server hits one of the pages to the local HTTP server and sends back to the client the source of the page as a string through the socket.

The next thing is webscarab to interfere before to load this content to the webengine and see the html page in the webview. After the changes to the code, I want to send the response from webengine to server, again through the socket.
To understand better what i want to do, below is the diagram of the architecture of my system.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: does webscarab works if you call page from regular browser like Firefox? If it doesn't then it's not an FX issue.

Comment: Yes webscarab works when I load the page from firefox or chrome, even when call the load method from the webengine it self, as I discribe above. The problem occurs  when I call the loadContent method of the webengine to load a local html file. In this case nothing happens, the main panel of the webscarab opens correctly, but the Edit Response and Edit request panels never appear on the screen. So it seems that webscarab do not understand that a page is loading in the engine to interfere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load your page from html using `loadContent()` there is no traffic outside of JVM. You make a String, you put it into `WebEngine` and it parses that string. No proxy, no web, no sockets unless your page refers to some web resources.

As a workaround you may try to use separate engine to provide local html as sites. E.g. [Jetty server](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/). In a Jetty you can introduce a simple handler which return string you need, then give corresponding url to `WebEngine`.